# Ubuntu 18.04 Mouse button mapping

Tags: mouse, gnome, ubuntu-18.04, xinput

I'm  difficulty programming button mappings for my anker A7851 mouse which has multiple non standard buttons, not all of which are recognized.

So far, I have tried using the standard gnome settings, gnome tweaks, the xinput utility and a utility called iwheel.
Gnome and Gnome tweaks had no support for most of what I want to do, and the existing settings for mouse don't seem to actually be applied.
I couldn't get iwheel up and running and xinput has a bit of a learning curve.
Even after reading the man pages i cannot figure out if it will do exactly what I
need, or how exactly to configure it.

In my case, xinput is recognizing 7 buttons(including scroll wheel function), where the mouse itself has 8. I tried adding the 8th button using the
--set-button-map option but for some reason it overwrote button 1. There was no change to the actual function of the mouse.
Assuming this is a syntax error and i was able to add button #8, I cannot figure out how I would be able to link that button to a function.

Does anyone has a possible solutions to this?

Comment: Maybe writing your own driver to monitor the device?

Comment: @user96931 that seems to be an option but I have extremely limited skills in that area. Are there some conf files somewhere that i can add a few lines to?